# How to display page according to the value which is typed in URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My existing URL is:
https://example.com/folder-name/file-name.php?id=16(dynamic)

On the basis of above URL, I am displaying a page of a particular user according to the id.

1. file-name.php- In it, I have written a database queries on the basis of which I am displaying user details.

Now, I want the URL as:
https://example.com/name/age/listen(static value)/

- Name and age is dynamic value

By accessing the name and age from URL, I want to display particular details by fetching from database.

Comment: Why would you not simply pass the info in the URL like you did in the previous case? `https://example.com/name/age/listen/?age=25&name=John`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PauloHgo I think the OP means the URL will be `https://example.com/John/25/listen` with no parameters.

Comment: Ah.... I see. In that case it would be just the case of forming that URL in a string and then redirecting the user to it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @SFTP yeah right, I want same url as you have written

Comment: Which web server are you using? Apache, for instance, should be able to handle this quite nicely with mod_rewrite, and from the strange tag for .htaccess it's a fair guess you might be using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameters from URL by using $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]. It will return all the parameters which you typed after site_url. Then you can use explode function to get parameters in an array and used it further for database queries.